Identical twin sisters fighting each other in a house fire
The final scene in this movie has identical twin sisters fighting each other in a house fire.
I saw the movie clip on you tube about 3 years ago. The twins seemed to be played by the same British actress who appeared to be her in 50s or early 60s. The movie was definitely made sometime during the last 30 years or less. The reason they were fighting is because one of them was married into a wealthy family and the other one wants to take her place by killing the other with a knife. The fire starts during their struggle. One chases the other up a stairway. There is a door with a glass pane in it at the top of the stairs. One closes the door but the other breaks the glass... 
Could be part of some kind of horror movie. The movie ends with one chasing the other back down the stairs and they are on top of each other on the floor struggling with the knife as the house fills with smoke. The very final scene shows the house from outside in the distance with fire raging from all the windows. 
It is definitely a drama with horror aspects.
Can anyone identify this movie?

Horror movie? Drama? Fighting like "pro" (combat trained) or people without training?

I wonder if the clip I saw was roughly based on real life twins Clare and Rachel Wallmeyer, 42?

I am not sure exactly which movie it is, but I think it's a remake of Alone , which is based on Agatha Christie's book Elephants Can Remember. Or another movie based on the same book.
There are many other similar movies in many languages with same plot (based on Elephants can remember)
Chaarulatha (Kannada Language Movie), Geethanjali (Malayalam Langiage Movie), Alone (Hindi Language Movie) are also having the same plot and the same climax scene that two twin sisters fighting each other in a house on fire.

No,it is not the same movie as the Hindi version of Alone . Neither twin is a ghost in the one I saw and it is not a Hindi movie at all.

Also the twins are alone together fighting during the house fire and both presumably die during the fire as the movie ends.

The actress who plays the dual role as identical twins looked very much like an older Senta Berger and may have been her. I think the movie was most likely a foreign language movie.
